# Oracle Apex referencing User Groups

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to build an application that will be used across 6 work sites.  I would like to have all staff details lodged in the same application and each staff member will have a 'Site' assigned to them (the city in which they work).  When a manager from that site uses the application I would like them to only see staff in the site that they have access to.

I have been struggling with this for a while.
I have set up all the tables and pages so that all staff can be seen.
I have created user groups and assigned different users to different groups (sites).  I dont know how to limit the access or even reference the group that a user is assigned to.

Any help on this topic would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance

Comment: You are using users and user groups defined through the user administration of apex itself?

Answer (score 0):

I have found a suitable solution myself.  I have created a Table called 'Tbl_000_UserAccess'
In this table there are 3 columns (ID, USER ID, Site ID).

I add the user and the site ID that they can view into this table.

Then I create a view on the staff table the restricts the records to the UserID of current User.  Here is my view coding for anybody that is interested:

CREATE OR REPLACE FORCE VIEW  "Vw_010_Staff" ("ID", "Emp No.", "First Name", "Last Name", "Team Leader", "Coach", "JE", "CD", "IRE", "FAM", "GB", "GST", "Emp", "SLS", "Bus RADC", "KS Ind", "KS N Ind", "Anon", "OB", "Resigned", "Reason", "Site") AS 
  select "Tbl_010_Staff"."ID" as "ID",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Employee Number" as "Emp No.",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."First Name" as "First Name",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Last Name" as "Last Name",
"Tbl_011_TeamLeaders"."First Name" || ' ' || "Tbl_011_TeamLeaders"."Last Name" as "Team Leader", 
"Tbl_012_Coaches"."First Name" || ' ' || "Tbl_012_Coaches"."Last Name" as "Coach",
"Tbl_014_JE"."JE" as "JE",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Customer Details" as "CDstuff",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."IR Essentials" as "IRE",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Family Tax Credits" as "FAM",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."General Business" as "GB",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."GST" as "GST",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Employers" as "Emp",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Student Loans" as "SLS",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Business Receivables" as "Bus RADC",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Kiwi Saver Ind" as "KS Ind",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Kiwi Saver NonInd" as "KS N Ind",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Anonymous" as "Anon",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Outbound" as "OB",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Inactive" as "Resigned",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Inactive Reason" as "Reason",
"Tbl_010_Staff"."Site" as "Site"

```
from (((("Tbl_010_Staff" left outer join "Tbl_011_TeamLeaders" on "Tbl_010_Staff"."Team Leader" = "Tbl_011_TeamLeaders"."ID")
    left outer join "Tbl_012_Coaches" on "Tbl_010_Staff"."Coach" = "Tbl_012_Coaches"."ID")
left outer join "Tbl_014_JE" on "Tbl_010_Staff"."JE" = "Tbl_014_JE"."ID")
left outer join "Tbl_000_UserAccess" on "Tbl_010_Staff"."Site" = "Tbl_000_UserAccess"."SiteID")

**where "Tbl_000_UserAccess"."SiteID" =
(Select "Tbl_000_UserAccess"."SiteID" 
    from "Tbl_000_UserAccess"
    where "Tbl_000_UserAccess"."UserID" = NVL(v('APP_USER'),USER))**
```

This has worked perfectly.  the only annoyance is that when a user is added to the schema, I will also need to add a record to the useraccess table.
Please be aware that the UserID is case sensative

Hope this helps